# ¿Como buscar mediante dos campos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, bootstrap

estoy tratando de crear un buscador mediante dos campos obligatorios. Es decir, supongamos que un paciente desea conocer el resultado de sus análisis, previamente alguien carga sus datos y le dice que para conocer su resultado debe ingresar su DNI y TramiteDNI obligatoriamente.

El formulario que tengo armado seria el siguiente:

index.php

```html
<div class="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center">
   <h1>CONSULTA DE RESULTADOS</h1>
      <div class="card card-body">
         <form action="resultados.php" method="GET">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>DNI:</label>
               <input type="text" name="dni" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese DNI" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Nro. de tramite:</label>
               <input type="text" name="tramitedni" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese nro. de trámite" required>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Consultar">
          </form>
       </div>
</div>
```

Luego de que el usuario ingrese esos dos campos (obligatoriamente), lo llevaría al resultado de sus análisis. Yo pensé en hacerlo como una búsqueda, aunque no se si es seguro que acceda a esos datos de esa manera. En fin, el lugar a donde lo envía es el siguiente:

resultados.php

```html
<div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center">CONSULTA DE RESULTADOS</h1>
            <div class="card card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control"><span style="font-weight: bold">DNI:</span> <?php $row['dni']; ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control"><span style="font-weight: bold">Nombre y apellido:</span> <?php $row['nombres']; ?>, <?php $row['apellidos']; ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control"><span style="font-weight: bold">Fecha de analisis:</span> <?php $row['fecharegistro']; ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control"><span style="font-weight: bold">Resultado:</span> <?php $row['resultado']; ?></label>
                    </div>
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-block" href="index.php" role="button">Otra consulta</a>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Y la parte PHP que uso en este ultimo archivo, es la siguiente:

```
<?php $dni = $_REQUEST['dni'];
      $tramitedni = $_REQUEST['tramitedni'];
        if (empty($dni)){ (aquí no se como poner dos variables o si se puede, me gustaría mejorar esto)
            header("Location: index.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM pacientes WHERE dni LIKE '%".$dni."%' AND tramitedni LIKE '%".$tramitedni."%' ORDER BY dni";
        $result_pacientes = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_pacientes)){ PARTE HTML }?>
```

Lo que necesito es que la búsqueda se haga si o si mediante esos dos campos.

Estoy usando PHP+MYSQL, HTML+CSS+BS4.

Comment: no entiendo bien tu pregunta... Te refieres a como hacer un if con dos campos? tipo `(empty($dni) || empty($tramitedni))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo más simple sería recoger los datos en una variable y luego comparar esas variables. Aquí, para más claridad en el código usaremos un operador ternario, que asignará el dato a cada variable o `NULL` en caso de no tener datos.

Implementaré también algunas prácticas recomendadas, como usar el método específico, por eso, en vez de `$_REQUEST` usaré `$_GET` (es el método por defecto cuando un formulario no tiene método indicado).

```
$dni = !empty($_GET['dni']) ? $_GET['dni'] : NULL;
$tramitedni = !empty($_GET['tramitedni']) ? $_GET['tramitedni'] : NULL;

if($dni && $tramitedni) {
    # Un Location no tiene ningún sentido aquí
    # Las concatenaciones internas sobran
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pacientes WHERE dni LIKE '%$dni%' AND tramitedni LIKE '%$tramitedni%' ORDER BY dni";
    $result_pacientes = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    #Leer los datos y decidir qué hacer, aquí si podría tener sentido el Location
} else {
    # Location o lo que sea cuando los datos no validen
}
```

### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Para evitarlo deberías implementar consultas preparadas. Un riesgo de *Inyección SQL* significa que un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular los datos que son pasados desde el formulario para hacer  daños muy graves en el sistema, dado que pasas en `$query` esos datos sin ninguna seguridad. ¡Por medio de la base de datos se puede incluso escribir en el sistema de archivos!

Comment: He probado tal cual me has dicho, pero no funciona, al momento de llenar el formulario en "index.php", me redirige a "resultados.php?dni=11111111&tramitedni=45787898789" por ejemplo, pero yo ahi mismo tengo unos inputs donde deberian aparecer los datos que trae la DB, pero aparece en blanco. Yo busco que mediante el ingreso de esos dos datos, pueda mostrarle otras columnas de la misma db.

Comment: @Imperius228 he respondido a lo que preguntabas, sobre verificar dos variables al mismo tiempo. El resto del código debes completarlo: lectura de la consulta, etc. Supongo que queda claro que este código va en `resultados.php`. Si no te funciona, dinos qué muestra, poniendo mensajes adecuados y verificando que la consulta no falla ni viene vacía.

Comment: Si, lo he colocado en `resultados.php` pero no funciona, envía los datos al parecer pero no puedo darme cuenta del error. Le adjunto un documento en pastebin con el código completo del archivo `resultados.php`, [enlace](https://pastebin.com/mhFsWYxq), que podría ser?

Comment: @Imperius228 tienes que depurar tu código. Primera depuración: pon un `var_dump($_GET);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Ya logre hacer que funcione, pero ahora no me funciona el header(location), vuelvo a poner el código dentro de un pastebin `resultado.php` [enlace](https://pastebin.com/ViH4nvPm), en este caso quiero que sea redirigido nuevamente al index, con un mensaje tipo alerta de boostrap.Tambien dejo el archivo `index.php` [enlace](https://pastebin.com/8CEPNHLZ). Gracias por el tiempo. PD: en la linea 61 del archivo ´resultado.php´ despues del "else" quiero que se ejecute ese mensaje y se redireccione, pero no funciona.